# Preparing data for timeline animation in QGIS

Tags: qgis, data, fields-attributes, time-series, spreadsheet

I have a data-spreadsheet containing a value-attribute that changes over time for a number of administrative units. I have a polygon layer as well with features for each of the administrative units. The spreadsheet containing the date looks like this:

[image]

I now want to use the built-in temporal control in QGIS 3.16 to visualise the change of the attribute-value for each administrative unit over time. I imported the spreadsheet as attribute data. Now the problem starts: how to join the attributes to the geometry? Each geometry (administrative unit) should contain for every time-stamp a separate value.

Having the Admin. units in the spreadsheet in the top row, I can't make a table-join with the polygon-layer. So I tried to first convert the spreadsheet in this way:

[image]

No I can joint these attributes using the Ad.Unit-field to the geometries of the administrative units. That works, however, I only get the first data-set per ad.unit (day 1). All the others are left out. But to be able to animate, I should have a value for each day (timestamp-field).

What I would like to achieve is a time-animated circle-marker whose size depend on the value-field for each day. How to achieve this?

Comment: Your time/date format needs to be correct example: YYYY-MM-DD see more https://medium.com/@tjukanov/geogiffery-in-a-nutshell-introduction-to-qgis-time-manager-31bb79f2af19

Comment: Yes, I have that, in principle, the timestamp-field works with the temporal controller. The problem is with joining the two layers: geometry and attributes

Comment: By the way, I spek about the native, built-in time  controller (since 3.14), not the timemanager plugin

Answer (score 1):

To create several new attributes for one feature on the layer `admin_units` from different features (rows) of the data-only layer `imp`, use field calculator. To get the `value` attribute for each row from `imp` to the corresponding new attribute in `admin_units` (where for each date in `timestamp` attribute, a separate field should be created), use this expression :

```
with_variable (
    'name',
    name,
    aggregate( 
        'imp',
        'array_agg',
        value,
        filter:=timestamp= to_date('2022-08-28') and ad_unit=@name
    )[0]
)
```

*Screenshot (be aware that the last field has a wrong fieldname - it should be `28-08-22` (not 29-08-22):*
[image]

Comment: I see what you did here, and it could be useful in many situations!  But what is the purpose of changing the imp record #4 timestamp day value from 28 to 29 in the admin_units field name?

Comment: That is an error, it should be 28, not 29, of course. Will add an explanation to the solution, thanks for drawing my attention to it!